# How to access subdomains in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

In my cucumber steps I need to find the subdomain so that I can query it against the database and find if the record was created. I would also like to know the best way to switch to the correct subdomain for the specific user. I am using the following:

- cucumber-rails 1.3.0
- rspec-rails 2.10.1
- mongoid

Here is what the current step definition looks like. But request is not the correct method here.

```
Then /^I should be on the ([^"]*) page$/ do |arg1|
  request.uri.should == "/#{arg1}"
end

Then /^I should be on the ([^"]*) subdomain$/ do |arg1|
  request.subdomain.should == arg1
end
```

Neither of these steps work because request is a method for making an actual http request in the selenium driver.

Comment: How are you getting your URL to begin with?  Do you have any code you can show us?

Comment: I am using the selenium web driver. I will update my post with the step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `browser` variable of some kind, something like this should work:

`browser.getLocation.should == "/#{arg1}"`

Comment: There was a browser object but it was buried deep within selenium. Thanks for the tip!